# How to detect the drag end event of an UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I need to get notified when an `UITableView`'s drag has come to an end.

But I'm working on an UITableView's category, so I can't use `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` to archive this.

I tried use KVO to observe on `dragging` Key Path:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dragging" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

But `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` didn't get called, since UITableView.dragging doesn't have and setter and this property is not compliant with KVO.

Is there any other method to archive this expect for using `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`?

Any help is grateful! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** My solution below was the first thing to come in mind and turned out to be rather hacky and may be unsafe to use in case Apple decides to change the internals of the `UIScrollView` class. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24358388/892696) suggested by Mazyod which should be safer and more straightforward.

---

This is implementation-dependent and may be changed by Apple in future iOS updates, but currently `UIScrollView` class seems to rely on gesture recognizers for managing user interaction and `UITableView` being a subclass of the scroll view class does the same.

If you go to UIScrollView.h of the UIKit framework, you can notice a suspicious `_pan` ivar which has an `id` type, but seems to actually be a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

So I've tried this, and it seems to work.

```
 [_tableView addObserver: self 
              forKeyPath: @"pan.state" 
                 options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                 context: nil];
```

When dragging the table view, `state` of the gesture recognizer changes several times, and when you stop dragging, `state` receives its last change to the value of `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`.

Please note that although this seems to do the trick, some other problem may stand in your way. It is generally not a good idea to override existing class methods in a category since the original implementation becomes inaccessible after that. Documentation on the [`NSKeyValueObserving`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) informal protocol states that

> NSObject provides an implementation of the NSKeyValueObserving protocol that provides an automatic observing capability for all objects.

So if you override `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` in a category, the default implementation will be inaccessible (and we cannot be sure that `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` do not user KVO for something). That may cause some unexpected errors.

Comment: How if I implemention `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` in some Class 'Foo', and UITableView category keep a instance of Foo?

Comment: Implementing `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` in a separate Foo class should indeed help with that 'overriding existing method in a category' issue.

Answer (score 8):

Egor Chiglintsev's answer reminded me I can observe the `panGestureRecognizer` property already exposed in `UIScrollView`. It should be much safer than `pan`. But then.. I found out I can just add myself as a target!

```
[_scrollView.panGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(gestureRecognizerUpdate:)];
```

This works great for me!

Comment: I guess that's the proper way it should be really done. Don't know why the first things coming in my mind are usually some runtime or KVO-related hacks. Thanks)