# I needed to listen out for changes to a UIScrollView but I couldn’t set the delegate in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, key-value-observing

I recently found myself in a situation where I needed to listen out for changes to a UIScrollView of which I couldn’t set the delegate. I have 2 views, they all want to be delegate of the scrollView but it only can set one view, how about the second view. My situation was I want get state `scrollViewWillEndDragging` to set scrollView's contentInset but I couldn’t set the delegate. maybe I can use KVO but I don't know how to do?

I found this solution in Objective-c. http://sam.dods.co/blog/2014/08/03/secondary-delegate/

but in Swift `'NSMethodSignature' is unavailable in Swift: NSInvocation and related APIs not available`

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: I have no ideas yet.

Comment: Please specify *why* you can't set the delegate, so we can understand the situation and propose better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Observing `pan.state` of a scroll view will help you.

See [How to detect the drag end event of an UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817047/how-to-detect-the-drag-end-event-of-an-uitableview)